# Creating a layer after using SelectLayerByAttribute_management

Tags: arcpy, layers, select-by-attribute, error-000840

Is it possible to use an existent layer to do a selection by attributes without having to use `MakeFeatureLayer_management` first? Because I already have a layer with the same name as the feature class "Rede_Cbr_MM_2008_proj".

Only this code works for me:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "S:/workspace/MSc_git/ArcGis/estagio_db.gdb"
workspace = "S:/workspace/MSc_git/ArcGis/Layers"
in_feature= "Rede_Cbr_MM_2008_proj"
tmp_layer="tmp_layer"

# # Set overwrite option
# arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#MakeFeatureLayer variables
where_clause='TSYSSET NOT LIKE \'%Metro%\''

try:
    #Make a layer from the feature class
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_feature,tmp_layer)   
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tmp_layer,"NEW_SELECTION",where_clause)

    # Write the selected features to a new featureclass
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tmp_layer, "Rede_Cbr_MM_2008_WithoutMetro")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

But if I try to use my layer using only `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` I get this error:

```
Executing: SelectLayerByAttribute S:/workspace/MSc_git/ArcGis/Layers/Rede_Cbr_MM_2008_proj.lyr NEW_SELECTION "TSYSSET NOT LIKE '%Metro%'"
Start Time: Sat Jul 20 21:49:55 2013
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000825: The value is not a layer or table view
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

Isn't the `SelectLayerByAttribute` supposed to take a layer as 1st parameter? I don't know I do I have to do this kind of "layer on the fly" (`tmp_layer`) and then select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Layer != Layer File

You need to create a **[Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000)** object from the layer file first - this should work:

```
tmp_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("S:/workspace/MSc_git/ArcGis/Layers/Rede_Cbr_MM_2008_proj.lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tmp_layer,"NEW_SELECTION",where_clause)
```

Comment: Uhm, ok, I really didn't realize that by reading the arcgis help. But we always have to create a in memory layer, either from a feature class or from an existent layer file, right?

Comment: Another way is to get a Layer object returned from those that exist within a map document (.mxd), a data frame within a map document, or layers within a layer (.lyr) file by using [**arcpy.mapping.ListLayers**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000002n000000).